# C++ function pointers and addresses

Tags: c++, reference

I'm trying to learn C++ and ran into this confusing example in the tutorial I'm using perhaps someone can clarify this for me.

The following code is from the tutorial.  I've put a "tag" (if you will `// <---` )indicating the parts that are confusing to me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CDummy {
  public:
    // signature: accepts an address 
    int isitme (CDummy& param);
};

// actual function that accepts an address passed in from main set to
// the param variable
int CDummy::isitme (CDummy& param) // <--- 1
{
```

Now here is where the confusing part comes.  I'm taking the address of 
an address variable???  Wasn't the address already passed in?

```
  if (&param == this) return true; // <--- 2
  else return false;
}

int main () {
  CDummy a;
  CDummy* b = &a;
  // passes in the class 
  if ( b->isitme(a) )
    cout << "yes, &a is b";
  return 0;
}
```

### Now below in the code that makes sense to me

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CDummy {
  public:
    int isitme (CDummy *param);
};

int CDummy::isitme (CDummy *param) // <--- 1
{
```

this part makes perfect sense.  param is a pointer and I'm comparing
the pointer of class a with the pointer of class b.

```
  if (param == this) return true; // <--- 2
  else return false;
}

int main () {
  CDummy a;
  CDummy *b = &a;
  // pass in the address.
  if ( b->isitme(&a) )
    cout << "yes, &a is b";
  return 0;
}
```

Which one of the code samples is correct? Correct in the sense that this is the preferred way to do it, because they both work. Also, why am I taking an address of an address in the first example?

Apologies if this has been answered before but I couldn't find it. 
Thanks

Comment: Two different meanings for the symbol `&`: one as an operator and one as part of a type declarator. `&i` is the address of `i`, but `int& i` is declaring `i` to be a reference to int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take you favorite C++ book and read about *references*.

In this declaration

```
int CDummy::isitme (CDummy& param)
```

`param` is not an address, as you seem to believe. It is a reference.

You are not the first one to be misled by the `&` character used in reference declarations. This question has been asked many times before on StackOverflow

[What is a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765999/what-is-a-reference-variable-in-c)

[What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)

but a book/guide/tutorial will make a better starting point, in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

```
int CDummy::isitme (CDummy& param) // <--- 1
```

In C++, the `&` means to [pass the parameter by *reference*](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/) rather than by value. It doesn't indicate an address.

Note that you might see `CDummy & param` or `CDummy &param`. It's all the same.

Answer (score 1):

The unary `&` returns the address of its operand. And when used in the parameters, it indicates a pass *by reference*.