# Reverse string code using passing by reference method not working

Tags: c++, string, reference

Please tell me why my code to reverse the input string is giving me various errors.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
void ReverseString(string &aString);
int main(){
    string info;
    cout << "What's your string?" << endl;
    getline(cin, info);
    ReverseString(info);
    cout << ReverseString(string info) << " compare with: " << info << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void ReverseString(string &aString){

for(int i = 0; i < aString.length(); i++)
    {
        string temp = 0; // initialize temporary string
        temp = temp + aString.at(aString.length() - 1 - i); // hold temporary string
        if(i => aString.length()) /*assign temp string to aString when all chars are processed*/
        {
            temp = &aString;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you use [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)?

Comment: What is the exact error you get ? Many times, the error message should point you in the direction to fix it.

Comment: This is a canonical example for Stroustrup's advice to use `<algorithm>`s.

Comment: `cout << ReverseString(string info)` that won't even compile. At least give a compilable example.

Comment: Well I think the problem is the compilation errors (plus the logic errors too).

Comment: @thokra: In this case, you don't even need an algorithm; you can construct the reversed string directly from a pair of reverse iterators.

Comment: Did you mean to put `temp` outside the loop?

Comment: Start again would be my advice, there are multiple problems here,

Comment: @JerryCoffin: That is so true - unless you're not in control of the construction itself, of course.

Comment: could someone please fix this code?

Comment: It can't be fixed, it needs to be rewritten.

Comment: ok thank you. what do you mean by "cout << ReverseString(string info) that won't even compile"? thank you again!

Comment: First thing is the function signature. You use the function as if it returned a string, but you have written a void function. Sort that out first, which do you want?

Comment: thank you for help. I will try to implement your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi you could simplify your code a lot by using the STL

for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string str = "Hello World";
    cout << str << endl; 
    std::reverse(str.begin() , str.end());
    cout << str << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

let me know if this is not suitable to your needs as theres a few other ways to do it too.

Without STL:

There are some corrections/changes to your code required, which I have supplied below.  However you may want to look at some documentation on referencing variables to get an idea of how it works, such as:

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/05/cpp-reference-variable/

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C++)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C++%29)

[What is a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765999/what-is-a-reference-variable-in-c)

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_references.htm

Correct reference and pointer use is a major part of C++ and allows for some of the most powerful functionality in the language, provided it is used correctly, or major headaches and mental scarring if used incorrectly, so it is worth, even essential, to have a firm grasp of them.

And even then expect the odd misuse to crop up every-so-often. :)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
void ReverseString(string &aString);
int main(){
    string info;
    cout << "What's your string?" << endl;
    getline(cin, info);
    cout << info << " compare with: ";
    ReverseString(info);
    cout << info << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void ReverseString(string &aString)
{

    int len = aString.length();
    string temp = aString;// initialize temporary string
    aString ="";
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        aString += temp[len - (1+ i)]; // assigns the reversed value to the referenced string
    }
}
```

Just noticed the quote below from @zac-howland : so true, I have however left the code in as an illustrative piece.  Provided some reading is done on this as well as plenty of experimentation I hope NewProgrammer will get the information and skill-set he needs to go forward.

Comment: thank you, but this is for homework that requires the use of ampersand cal by reference method. Thank you anyway.!

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

string info;
string rvrs(string &str)
{
    std::reverse(str.begin(),str.end());
    return str;
}
int main()
{
    cout<<"What is your string :: ";
    getline(cin,info);
    cout<<rvrs(info);
    cout<<endl; 
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of problems.

```
    string temp = 0; // initialize temporary string
```

It doesn't really make sense to initialize a string to `0`. Just `string temp;` would be fine here.

```
    temp = temp + aString.at(aString.length() - 1 - i); // hold temporary string
```

That's not quite how I'd do things, but I guess it should work.

```
    if(i => aString.length())
```

This condition doesn't seem to make sense. Your loop is defined to iterate with `i` going from 0 to the length of the string -1, so it can never be greater than or equal to the string length.

```
    /*assign temp string to aString when all chars are processed*/
    {
        temp = &aString;
    }
```

Here the code doesn't match the comment. The comment says you're going to assign to `aString`, but the code assigns something to `temp`. The comment is probably closer to what you really want. But you still need to fix the condition, and probably want to do this after the loop has finished executing. So in pseudo-code, you'd end up with something like:

```
for (all characters in the string)
    add the next character in the string to the end of temp
assign temp back to the original string
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few syntactical errors in addition to your logical ones:

```
cout << ReverseString(string info) << " compare with: " << info << endl;
```

`ReverseString(string info)` will pass in an empty string to your `ReverseString` function (if it even compiles - which looks like it should not since you have 2 `info`'s in the same scope).  What you wanted is:

```
cout << ReverseString(info) << " compare with: " << info << endl;
```

In your reverse function, you only need to go to `length() / 2`.

Since you are passing by reference, changes you make to the string within the function will be reflected in the object you passed into it.  That is, the original `info` will be reversed.  If you want it to operate on a copy, you need to pass it by copy, not by reference.

Finally, `cout << ReverseString(info)` is not useful (if it even compiles) as `ReverseString` returns a `void`.  You should have it return a `string` (the reversed string).

Comment: The reason `cout << ReverseString(string info)` doesn't compile is nothing to do with having 2 `info`'s in the same scope.  It's a function declaration in the middle of an expression. It's complete nonsense, the OP simply doesn't know basic C++.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Understood.  There were so many syntactical issues with that statement alone that I didn't want to even attempt to list them all.