# What errors do following code have?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, reference

I am still a beginner in C++, and I am supposed to find the errors in the following code.

```
1 class Thing
2 {
3    public:
4       char c;
5       int *p;
6       float& f;
7       Thing(char ch, float x) { c = ch; p = &x; f = x; }
9 };
```

I understand that in the sixth line there is an error: reference f need to be initialized. But I am confused about the seventh line. It looks like a constructor, but I cannot make sure p = &x; is correct? Also, If I want to correct the error of the reference initialization, how can I do it?

Comment: You're pretty much there. Now you just need to keep thinking and researching to discover how to initialise a reference, and you're done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing to do to find out if there are errors is simply to compile it <sup>(1)</sup>.

If you do that, you'll find at least two problems:

- references should be initialised; and
- you can't assign a float-pointer to and int-pointer.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> As per this transcript:

```
$ g++ -c -o prog.o prog.cpp
prog.cpp: In constructor ‘Thing::Thing(char, float)’:
prog.cpp:7:7: error: uninitialized reference member in ‘float&’ [-fpermissive]
       Thing(char ch, float x) { c = ch; p = &x; f = x; }
       ^
prog.cpp:6:14: note: ‘float& Thing::f’ should be initialized
       float& f;
              ^
prog.cpp:7:43: error: cannot convert ‘float*’ to ‘int*’ in assignment
       Thing(char ch, float x) { c = ch; p = &x; f = x; }
                                           ^
```

Comment: Since x here: Thing(char ch, float x) is passed by value, I am still able to access the address of x?

Comment: @Aria, no, and that will become clear as you clean up each problem and try to recompile :-) The object `x`, as an formal rather than actual parameter, will disappear once the function returns so setting up a reference to it that will itself survive function exit is a no-no.

Answer (score 0):

```
p = &x;
```

is not right since `p` is of type `int*` and `&x` is of type `float*`.

```
f = x;
```

is most likely not what you intended. You probably want to `f` to be a reference to `x`. The above line does not do that. It assigns the value of `x` to the object referenced by `f`.

If you want `f` to be a reference to `x`, you need to initialize it as:

```
Thing(char ch, float& x) : f(x) { ... }
               //  ^^^ different from your signature
```

Using

```
Thing(char ch, float x) : f(x) { ... }
```

is problematic since `f` will be a dangling reference once the function returns.

Comment: Can I just change this line: Thing(char ch, float x) { c = ch; p = &x; f = x; } in to Thing(char ch, float x) { c = ch; &f = x; }, and also delete the sixth line?

Comment: No, you cannot. Your question convinces me that you don't understand how reference types in C++ work. Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765999/what-is-a-reference-variable-in-c.