# C++: "Field 'object_var' must be initialized" in constructor of Base class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, parameters, initialization

I am programming a polymorphic program in C++ that requires the use of Derived/Inherited classes. My base class is called `ClassA` and my Derived class is called `ClassB`. I have a separate class called `varClass` that is the datatype for a parameter in the constructor of my Base class, `ClassA`. I get this error message in the following constructor in `ClassA.cpp`:

> Field 'object_var' must be initialized

```
#include "ClassA.h"
#include "varClass.h"

ClassA::ClassA(const classVar &O, const int &p) {}
```

Why must objects from a separate concrete class be initialized before allowing them to be used a parameters of functions in separate classes? I have tried putting a forward declaration of the `classVar` class in `ClassA` with no luck. How can I fix this to allow an argument of a datatype from a separate class? If I give it an initialization, how can I ensure each value passed to this constructor is unique and not just overridden by the initialization value?

Here is the rest of the relevant code. I am not going to show the Derived classes as I do not believe they are part of the problem, but decided to mention them since I am a novice programmer and that could possibly be the issue.

```
// ClassA.h

#ifndef CLASSA_H
#define CLASSA_H

#include "varClass.h"

class ClassA {

protected:
    const classVar &object_var; // The problem lies here
    unsigned var1;

 // ... more code follows

public:
    ClassA(const object &O, const int &p);

// ... more code follows

};

#endif
```

Header and implementation of `objectVar` class are irrelevant to issue. That class is a standard concrete class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialize [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765999/what-is-a-reference-variable-in-c) in the [constructor's initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
ClassA(const classVar &O, const int &p)
 : object_var(O) {    
}
```

P.S. Make sure constructor's signatures in header and source files match.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`object_var` needs to be initialized in the constructor because it is a reference.  There is no other way to have it refer to something.

Comment: Can you give an example of the proper way to do that? How can I initialize it to ensure that values passed to it are unique and not just the same as the initialization value?

Comment: @revolution9540 Something like `ClassA::ClassA(const classVar &O, const int &p): object_var(O) {}

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of doing it that way.