# C++ field value on object is not being retained

Tags: c++

So I'm coming from the C# word trying to program my Particle Photon in C++. I'm trying to make use of a class to help organize the data better.

I made a definition of a class called Lane:

```
#ifndef Lane_h
#define Lane_h
#include "application.h"

class Lane {

 public:

  Lane(int sensorId, String laneName);
  Lane();

  int
    readSensor(void),
    getWinningOrder(void);

  bool
    hasFinished(void);

  void
    setWinningOrder(int order);

  String
    getName();

  int
    winningOrder;


 private:
    int 
        sensor;

    String  
        name;

};

#endif
```

Then I made the cpp file:

```
#include "Lane.h"
#include "application.h"

Lane::Lane(int sensorId, String laneName){
    sensor = sensorId;
    name = laneName;
    winningOrder = 0;
}

Lane::Lane(){
    winningOrder = 0;
}

int Lane::readSensor(){
    int value = analogRead(sensor);
    return value;
}

String Lane::getName(){
    return name;
}

bool Lane::hasFinished(void){
    Particle.publish("DEBUG", name + " has a winning order of: " + String(winningOrder));
    return winningOrder != 0;
}
```

So far so good.

Now in my .ino file that Particle executes the loop in I read from and set my field. (I've slightly condensed this file to make it easier to read.)

```
// This #include statement was automatically added by the Particle IDE.
#include "Lane.h"

Lane lanes[] = {
    Lane(A5, "Lane 1"), 
    Lane(A4, "Lane 2"), 
    Lane(A3, "Lane 3"), 
    Lane(A2, "Lane 4")
    };
int winningPlace = 1;

void setup() {

}

void loop() {
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < arraySize(lanes); i++) {
        Lane lane = lanes[i];
        int value = lane.readSensor();

        if(value + sensitivity < initalValues[i] && !lane.hasFinished()){
            Particle.publish("DEBUG", lane.getName() + " pre-set field value is " + lane.winningOrder);
            lane.winningOrder = winningPlace++;
            Particle.publish("DEBUG", lane.getName() + " set field value is " + lane.winningOrder);
        }

    }
}
```

The first time through the loop the pre-set debug value returns 0 and after set value returns 1 as expected. The next time through the loop it enters the if statement dispute !lane.hasFinished(). The pre-set returns 0 as if it was looking at a new object or something. What am I missing here? Why is the field's value not persisting on the object between cycle's in the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Lane lane = lanes[i];
```

makes a copy of `lanes[i]` - any modification to `lane` won't affect the element. Try a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765999/what-is-a-reference-variable-in-c):

```
Lane &lane = lanes[i];
```

`lane` is an alias for `lanes[i]`. Using `lane` is as if you were using `lanes[i]` and by assigning to `lane.winningOrder`, you'll actually assign to the referenced `lanes[i]`'s `winningOrder`. There are no copies.

Also start using [member initialization lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list) instead of assignments and `const` qualifiers for member functions.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're creating a new object each time.

```
Lane lane = lanes[i];
```

This creates a new instance of the `Lane` class called "lane", whose contents are copy-constructed from `lanes[i]`.

Then, the rest of the loop works with this `lane` object. It's contents get twiddled, as needed, and afterwards, this object gets destroyed.

Next time through the loop you make another copy of the same, still unused object.

Changing it to a reference should get your desired behavior.

```
Lane &lane = lanes[i];
```