# C++: reference and lifetime extension using const

Tags: c++, reference, constants, copy-constructor, object-lifetime

This refers to the C++ programming language. Assume we have a class `C` and do this:

```
C var1 = C(init_parameters);

C& var2(var1);
```

**Question 1:** 
If we change *var2*, for example `var2.memberA = 3`, is this affecting also `var1`? Or did we create a new object so that `var2` is not referencing `var1`?

**Question 2:**
Assume we have a function like this:

```
const C& f(C var1) {
  const C& tmp(var1);
  return tmp;
}
```

Can we now call the above function, e.g. `value = f(var1)` and get a valid reference `value`? In principle the return reference is out of scope but is the `const` extending the lifetime? What happens if `var1` is modified or deleted, does this affect the constant reference `value`? In other words and for the sake of clarity, can I use the variable `value` as if it was a copy of `var1`?

Comment: "here we call the copy constructor" Not really. `var2` is a reference.

Comment: Can you kindly explain and I will correct my statement?

Comment: "`var2` is a reference to `var1`" would be accurate.

Comment: Check your post for typos before hitting Submit.

Comment: One question per question, please.

Comment: ok, done. I removed the copy constructor wording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C& var2(var1);` and `const C& tmp(var1);` do not call any special member functions. You're declaring [references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765999/what-is-a-reference-variable-in-c) - aliases for the referenced objects/variables (yes, changes made to `var2` are actually made **through** `var2` to `var1`).

Concerning lifetime extension, that applies to **binding rvalues to `const&`**. `var1` is an lvalue and its lifetime is fixed to its scope.

To the second example, you can't return a reference (even to `const`) to a local variable. An alias doesn't change that. All that the caller will get is a dangling reference.

Comment: could you make and example of lifetime extension by binding rvalues to const& ? Thx

Comment: @Mannaggia [This](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/).