# Why if I use reference I don't need to deference a vector before using operator [] on it?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

If I pass a vector by reference to a function:

```
void QuadraticInterpolateArray(vector<double> &b) {
    double step = 12.2;
    for (int j = 0; j < b.size(); j++) {
        b[j] = step;
    }
}
```

I don't need later to deference `b` when I need to access to its value by using operator []. Instead, if I pass vector by pointer:

```
void QuadraticInterpolateArray(vector<double> *b)
```

I need (*b)[j] later.

In both case I'm passing the "address" of that vector.
Why with reference it works and with pointer doesn't? Its just by design?

Comment: You never "dereference" references. You only dereference pointers.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: See also [*what is a reference variable in C++?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765999/what-is-a-reference-variable-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because references are automatically dereferenced by the compiler.

This was introduced by C++ to simplify C's pointers.

And yes, this is a design choice.

Comment: References were introduced in order to accommodate operator overloading.

Comment: Yes, it would be hard with pointers.