# Would std::vector shrink to fit invalidate a reference to the vector itself?

Tags: c++, vector

I want to know the precise meaning that
`std::vector<T>::shrink_to_fit(new_capacity)` would invalidate reference.

> "If a reallocation happens, all iterators, pointers and references
>   related to the container are invalidated. Otherwise, no changes." --

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/shrink_to_fit/

Test code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
class Test {
public:
    Test(const std::vector<int>& a) : _a(a) {}
    void print() const {
        std::cout << "[";
        for (auto x:_a) std::cout << " " << x;
        std::cout << " ]\n";
    }   
    const std::vector<int>& _a; 
};
int main() {
    std::vector<int> a;
    a.reserve(100);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) a.push_back(i);
    Test t(a);
    t.print();
    a.shrink_to_fit();
    t.print(); // will this always work as expected?
}
```

If `new_capacity` is less than `old_capacity` (so the capacity of the `vector` shrinks), can the reference (the `_a` attribute of the test class) be invalidated?

Comment: Better reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit

Comment: cplusplus.com is full of mistakes so use one of the good websites like Cppreference.com

Comment: it seems that the war between the two sites would burn this account to ash. oh well. I just pick the top result of google.

Comment: @rxu - You might want to start here [What is a reference variable in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765999/what-is-a-reference-variable-in-c).

Comment: @NicolBolas I wish there is a way to tell google not to show me this site when I search for C++ docs

Comment: @Slava just start all your searches with `-site:cplusplus.com` so for example search for `-site:cplusplus.com shrink_to_fit`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah that's to much to type, easier to filter manually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the passage you are referring to means is that iterators or references to elements with the vector being resized can become invalidate.

In the case where `_a` is a reference, as your comment suggests, `_a` will continue to be a valid reference to the *vector*, but any iterators or references to elements *within* `_a` will be made invalid.

Comment: my bad... i mean `std<int>& _a;`

Comment: @rxu Edited to reflect that.

Comment: `_a is not a reference, but instead is a copy` but it is a reference in OP example

Comment: @marcinj In the original version of his example it was not a reference, but you are correct in that I need to remove that part.

Answer (score 3):

Yes `std::vector::shrink_to_fit()` would invalidate references if reallocation occurs. But that unrelated to you sample code - references or pointers to data that vector holds would be invalidated, not reference to vector itself:

```
std::vector<int> v( 10 );
std::vector<int> &vref = v;
int &ref = v[0];
v.resize(2);
v.shrink_to_fit();
// now ref could be invalid, but vref is perfectly fine
```

Answer (score 3):

> If new_capacity is less than old_capacity (so the capacity of the vector shrinks), can the reference (the _a attribute of the test class) be invalidated?

no, `Test::_a` will not be invalidated after:

```
a.shrink_to_fit();
```

if you would have a `std::vector<int>::iterator _aitr;`, which would point to some element of `a`, then such iterator would be invalidated.

Comment: I would expect this is the case, because I think the vector is an object with a pointer to the actual memory that holds the data. shrink to fit might change this pointer, but a reference to the vector should still be fine.

Comment: @rxu exactly, that is true