# What does "const int&" do as a return type?

Tags: c++, function, reference, max, constants

```
const int& max(int a[], int length)
{

int i=0;

    for(int j=0; j<length; j++)
        if(a[j]>a[i]) i=j;
    return a[i];
}

int main(){

    int array[] = {12, -54, 0, 123, 63};
    int largest;
    largest = max(array,5);
    cout<< "Largest element is " << largest << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So my question is, what does "const int&" do as a return type? Why I'm returning a value while function expect a reference?

Comment: You wrote the code - what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: It is a code from my lecture notes, it surely returns the largest number in the array but ı have never seen a usage like this. As ı asked above, why ı use "&" and why ım returning value?

Comment: If this is really code from your course, and if that course doesn't explain the various meanings of `&`, then I suggest you need to be on a different course.

Comment: Helpful reading: [What is a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765999/what-is-a-reference-variable-in-c). and this leads into [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)

Comment: That said, a constant reference to an `int` isn't all that useful. You don't save on much copying, possibly even copy more, and you can't write to it.

Comment: I do not think this could be from any decent notes, the int[] parameter isn't even named (I think it would be `a`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, returning a reference avoids that the return value gets copied, and (if it is not `const`-qualified) gives you the opportunity to change the "original" value. A return type `const T&` is often used in conjunction with objects of class type, e.g. `std::vector`, where copying could result in (unwanted) overhead. In conjunction with elementary data types like `int`, however, passing back a `const int&` is likely to be more overhead than copying the raw int value.

Further, in your example, if you assign the result of type `const int&` to a non-reference type, e.g. `int largest = max(...)`, the return value is "dereferenced" and assigned by value. So you can change the variable's content as it is a copy of the `const`-referenced value. If you have a type `const int&`, and you assign it to a variable of type `const int&`, then you get a reference, yet the compiler will not allow you the change it's contents.

So the only thing where passing back a reference to `int` would be without `const`, which will then allow you to alter the contents of the "origninal" value.
See the following code; Hope it helps a bit:

```
int& max(int a[], int length) {
    return a[3];
}

const int& maxConst(int a[], int length) {
    return a[3];
}

int main(){

    int array[] = {12, -54, 0, 123, 63};

    int largest = max(array,5);
    cout<< "Largest element (value) is " << largest << endl;
    largest = 10;
    cout << "Element at pos 3 is: " << array[3] << endl;

    int largestConst = maxConst(array,5);
    cout<< "Largest element (value) is " << largestConst << endl;
    largestConst = 10;
    cout << "Element at pos 3 is: " << array[3] << endl;

    int &largestRef = max(array,5);
    cout<< "Largest element (ref) is " << largestRef << endl;
    largestRef = 10;
    cout << "Element at pos 3 is: " << array[3] << endl;

    const int &largestRefConst = maxConst(array,5);
    cout<< "Largest element (value) is " << largestRefConst << endl;
    // largestRefConst = 10;  // -> cannot assign to variable with const-qualified type
    //cout << "Element at pos 3 is: " << array[3] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Largest element (value) is 123
Element at pos 3 is: 123
Largest element (value) is 123
Element at pos 3 is: 123
Largest element (ref) is 123
Element at pos 3 is: 10
Largest element (value) is 10
```