# What does "friend istream & operator >> (istream &, class_name &) ;" means?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int size = 3;
class vector {
   int v[size];

    public:
        vector(); 
        vector(int *x);
        friend vector operator * (int a, vector b); 
        friend vector operator * (vector b, int a); 
        friend istream & operator >> (istream &, vector &);
        friend ostream & operator << (ostream &, vector &);
    };
}
```

As in the above code, i cannot grasp what

```
friend istream & operator >> (istream &, vector &);
```

Here what i know, that stream is used for input streaming of data and ostream for output but what does istream & means before operator overloadin of >>.

Comment: That line declares a function to be a friend of the class. If that does not make sense, I recommend spending some time with [a good textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and understanding the fundamentals of the language.

Comment: [What is a reference variable in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2765999/27678)

Comment: It means that this function that returns an `std::istream` object and takes an `std::istream`  object by reference and an object of your class is a `friend` of your class. Which means it can access your `private/protected/public` data (full access). Remember a friend class or function is not a part of your class.

Answer (score -1):

It means that it returns a reference to the `istream` object. This is necessary for operator chaining as you're used to with `cout`:

```
std::cout << "foo" << "bar";
```

Without returning a reference to itself, this part : `<< "bar"`, wouldn't be possible.

Comment: But for that it doesn't necessarily need to make friends. Friend is only necessary if the operator needs private access to a class. This is often the case, but e.g. a completely public struct can have external operators, which (obviously) don't need to be friends with the struct.

Comment: @user2328447 Good thing that OP didn't ask about that then.