# push back a new vector into a vector

Tags: c++

I read the following code piece.

```
vector<vector<int>> result;
//level is an integer. 
if (level > result.size())
     result.push_back(vector<int>());
```

I'm wondering:
What does `vector<int>()`  create, an object or a pointer of vector?

I think it should be a vector object, instead of a pointer of vector. Otherwise, it won't compile.

However, I feel that `vector<int>()` is similar to `new vector<int>()` .

Maybe I missed something?

I really appreciate it if you could point out the knowledge point I missed.

Thank you very much!

Comment: There is no `new`. The presence or absence of `new` is a big deal.

Comment: You can just do `push_back()` here.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux What do you mean by that? `push_back` takes an argument. Or do you just mean that `new` is unnecessary (and actually wrong) here?

Comment: @Kevin My mistake, I meant to write `emplace_back()`.

Comment: I guess https://stackoverflow.com/a/22146244/8120642 is obligatory here.

Answer (score 3):

Both cases are similar in that they provide a real, honest-to-god object. The differences are in how you access it and how long it lives.

`vector<int>()` creates an object in Automatic storage with [Automatic storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration). You can consider this one an object that you can hold in your digital hand, but only temporarily. Without an associated identifier it [goes out of scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) and vanishes, is destroyed, at the end of the line. Before destruction it is copied into `result`. With an identifier (eg. `vector<int> vec;`), an Automatic variable lasts until the identifier reaches the end of its scope.

`new vector<int>()` creates an object in Dynamic storage with [Dynamic storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) and gives you a pointer to it. This object is out there somewhere and all you "hold" is information about how to find it. Couple problems in this case. You've noticed the first, `result` will not accept a pointer to a `vector`. It wants the real thing. The other problem is objects with Dynamic storage duration hang around until they are manually destroyed with `delete` or the process ends. Unless you have a pointer to it, the memory is lost, floating through space without a tether you can use to access and delete it.

In general, avoid `new` unless you find one of the rare cases where you cannot avoid it, and in those cases [prefer a smart pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one).

Comment: nit "makes an object in Dynamic storage" -> "creates an object with *allocated storage duration* with life that extends until it is deleted or the program ends" (but kudos for the accurate and colorful description)

Comment: Can I think in this way: vector<int>() return a reference. Without assigning the reference to a variable (or without using the reference), the object of the reference is destroyed automatically? This is like the reference mechanism in Java?

Comment: @Mike Best not to. [A reference in C++ is its own thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765999/what-is-a-reference-variable-in-c), so be careful how you use the term. While the destruction of an object in Java and a Automatic variable in C++ is handled automatically for you that's where the similarity ends.

Comment: The biggest difference that you can notice (the stuff going on behind the scenes can be dramatically different) is probably that you never know exactly when a Java object will be destroyed, but the Automatic C++ variable is destroyed exactly on schedule and in a predefined order. [This guarantee allows you to take precise control of resources.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii) Closely following this is the notion of [Value Semantics](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/value-vs-ref-semantics)

Comment: Interesting side-reading on one of the big ideological differences: [Raymond Chen's Everybody thinks about garbage collection the wrong way](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203)