# Confuse about & and * in the C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I just learned C++, and I don't understand the below:

The code part:

```cpp
int *i = new int;
*i = 0;
int &j = *i;
j++;
```

Question: which the meaning of the last line: `j++`?
Answer: Increments the value pointed to by `i` by one.

My confusion:
I am not sure the meaning of `int &j = *i;`

What's the relationship between `j` and pointer `i`? `j` is the pointer or other?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765999/what-is-a-reference-variable-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

> I am not sure the meaning of int &j = *i; what's the relationship between j and pointer i? j is the pointer or other?

`int &j` is declaring a variable `j`, of type `int&`, or integer reference (see [What is a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2765999/2602718)).

`int &j = *i` is assigning the value at address `i` to the reference variable `j`. So whenever you modify `j`, you'll be modifying `*i` (and vice versa).

See also: [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57483/2602718)

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure the meaning of `int &j = *i;`

`i` has been previously initialised as a pointer to a (dynamically allocated using operator `new`) `int`.   `*i` is a reference to that same dynamically allocated `int`.

In the declaration,  `int &j` declares `j` to be a reference to an `int`.    The `= *i` causes `j` to be a reference to the same `int` as `*i`.

In subsequent code where `j` is visible,  `j` is now a reference to (an alternative name, or an alias, for) the `int` pointed to by `i`.

Any operation on `j` will affect that `int`, in exactly the same way that doing that same operation on `*i` would.

So,   `j++` has the effect of post-incrementing `*i`.

Be aware of rules of operator precedence and associativity though.

- `++*i` and `++j` are equivalent because the pre-increment (prefix `++`) and `*` (for pointer dereference) have the same precedence and associativity.
- However,  `*i++` is NOT equivalent to `j++`, since post-increment (postfix `++`) has higher precedence than the `*`.    So `*i++` is equivalent to `*(i++)` but `j++` is equivalent to `(*i)++`.