# error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘Position&’ to an rvalue of type ‘Position’

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, error-handling, reference

When I try to compile my program, my Race.cc file has an error.

```
 error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘Position&’ to an rvalue of type ‘Position’
 view.update(tortoise->getCurrPos(), tortoise->getCurrPos(), tortoise->getAvatar());
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
```

I'm struggling to figure out how to resolve these and would appreciate some help. I don't know why calling `update(Position&, Position&, char)` from View.cc gets an error on the first parameter only and not the second considering I'm inputting the exact same thing. The line `tortoise->getCurrPos()` should return a Position data type as shown in Runner.cc, and the parameter asks for a Position type so I don't get why it's not working.

Race.cc

```
Race::Race(){ 
    Runner* tortoise = new Runner("Tortoise", 'T', 100, 1);
  
    view.update(tortoise->getCurrPos(), tortoise->getCurrPos(), tortoise->getAvatar());
}
```

View.cc

```
void update(Position& oldPos, Position& newPos, char avatar){
}
```

Comment: `new` returns a pointer, not an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `update()` is looking to take a `Position` by reference so that it can make modifications and have them percolate back to the object you're passing. However, `tortoise->getCurrPos()` returns a `Position` *copy*. If you want the changes in `update()` to affect your `tortoise`'s `Position` member, you'll need to have `getCurrPos()` return its `Position` by reference.

```
Position Runner::getCurrPos() {
```

Should become

```
Position& Runner::getCurrPos() {
```

For more, you can read up at [What is a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2765999/2602718)