# What is the significance of int &x declaration in class definition in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, pass-by-reference, declaration

```
class Pointer {
private:
    int &x;
public:
    Pointer(int &y) : x(y) {}
    int getT() { return x; }

};

int main()
{
    int w = 40;
    Pointer test(w);
    std::cout << &test <<' ' << &w;
}
```

What is the significance of the int &x declaration in the class definition? I understand that the int &y passed as a parameter for the constructor is the value passed by reference, but what about int &x as this type of declaration is showing me an error inside the main() function?

Comment: what is the error you see? Your code as it is compiles please show a [mre]

Comment: In this context `x` is a [reference variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765999/what-is-a-reference-variable-in-c). It has similar semantics to the reference parameter `int& y`: It is a reference to another `int`. In the case of `Pointer test(w);`, `test.x` will be a reference to `w`.

Comment: Maybe, you should try making your code `int &getT()` and outputting `std::cout << &test.getT() << ' ' << &w`. `w` in `main` points to the same location in memory as `x`. I'd also recommend renaming `x` to `t` or `getT` to `getX`. Be careful with references like these too. It's prone to error to have a private `x` point to the exact place in memory as a different variable that can be changed without `Pointer` knowing it. In this case, copying the reference to `w` is  most likely the same amount of work as passing `w` by reference too since `int` is so small.

Answer (score 2):

In the both cases in the constructor declaration

```
Pointer(int &y) : x(y) {}
```

and in the data member declaration

```
int &x;
```

there is declared a reference.

After calling the constructor

```
Pointer test(w);
```

the object test contains a reference to the object `w` passed by reference.

So for example you could write

```
int w = 40;
Pointer test(w);

std::cout << test.get() << '\n';
```

and the output will be

```
40
```

Now you can change the variable `w` as for example

```
w = 100;
```

and this statement

std::cout << test.get() << '\n';

will output

```
100
```

because it outputs a value of the same object stored in the object test by reference.

The reference `x` will be valid in the object `test` while the referenced object `w` is itself alive.